# If statements to validate special characters and lowercase letters

Tags: python

The code below is in python 3

I have wrote a function that validates if a password that came from a dictionary is lower or upper case. The code is below.

```
def validatePassword(password):
    upperFlag = False
    lowerFlag = False
    specialFlag = False
    special = "$!&*"
    for char in password:
        if password.islower():
            lowerFlag = True
        elif password.isupper():
            upperFlag = True
        elif char in special:
            specialFlag = True
    return len(password) >= 8 and \
              lowerFlag and \
              upperFlag and \
              specialFlag
```

this is the output I get
Validate Passwords in Check File

```
                           March2021            INVALID
                         iudj8&neB09            INVALID
                           MyDogWo0f            INVALID
                             mv3m959            INVALID
                  ven1vid1v1c1Iulius            INVALID
                           123456789            INVALID
                         abcdefgcijk            INVALID
                          What#ItN0w            INVALID
                       windsofchange            INVALID
                       HelloMyNameIs            INVALID
                             4584208            INVALID
                             4586300            INVALID
                          Anniv&0629            INVALID
                           BDay@1955            INVALID
                          BigBadW0d!            INVALID
                       !Rf0donotcare            INVALID
                          R85r!4L145            INVALID
                           S3att!eWa            INVALID
                          SONameHere            INVALID
                              Abc!23            INVALID
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I over complicating it?

Comment: Inside loop, your iterator is `char` but you are validating with `password.islower()` and yes you are over complicating things. and `islower()` and `isupper()` will return `True/False` based on whole string.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer, tl;dr

Your logic was faulty. Here's an improved code:

```py
def validatePassword(password):
    upper = any(letter.isupper() for letter in password)
    lower = any(letter.islower() for letter in password)
    specials = "$!&*"
    special = any((s in password) for s in specials)
    return all([special, lower, upper, len(password) >= 8])
```

### Explanation

- Python has an in-built functions for matching *any* or *all* conditions in a series of conditions. I used the function `any()` and checked uppercase and lowercase cases for each letter in the password.
- The syntax `do_sth for x in list` is a short-hand way of looping through the range of length. It's also handy for making n-dimensional lists like `[[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(6)]` which will give you a 2-d 5x6 list of zeros.
- You can check if a string contain some other string with `target in source`. That's how I checked for special characters.
- Password length is checked at the return statement.

### Results

```sh
March2021            : False
iudj8&neB09          : True
MyDogWo0f            : False
mv3m959              : False
ven1vid1v1c1Iulius   : False
123456789            : False
abcdefgcijk          : False
What#ItN0w           : False
windsofchange        : False
HelloMyNameIs        : False
4584208              : False
4586300              : False
Anniv&0629           : True
BDay@1955            : False
BigBadW0d!           : True
!Rf0donotcare        : True
R85r!4L145           : True
S3att!eWa            : True
SONameHere           : False
Abc!23               : False
```

Answer (score 1):

Before posting the exact code, I would like to tell you few points that will help you finding bug and fixing them

#### Tips for Debugging:

- Use more prints statement to check variable values
- Read about the functions you are trying to use
- Enable debug points and execute program step by step.

Please read through the about built-in functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) , their input and return values.

For Reference:

#### [islower](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/islower.html) :

```
Returns a Boolean stating whether the string (entire string) is in lower case.

"abcd".islower() will return True
"aBcd".islower() will return False
```

#### [isupper](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/isupper.html) :

```
Returns a Boolean stating whether the string (entire string) is in upper case.


"ABCD".isupper() will return True
"ABcD".isupper() will return False
```

### Working code

```
def validatePassword(password):
    upperFlag = False
    lowerFlag = False
    specialFlag = False
    special = "$!&*"
    for char in password:
        if char.islower():    # password.islower (will tell entire string is lower or not)
            lowerFlag = True
        elif char.isupper():  # password.islower (will tell entire string is upper or not)
            upperFlag = True
        elif char in special:
            specialFlag = True
    return len(password) >= 8 and \
              lowerFlag and \
              upperFlag and \
              specialFlag
```